# CSS: font remained as Arial after changing the font-family to -apple-system fonts

Tags: css, font-family

I want to use the font-family used by Airbnb for their website on my website. It is "Circular, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif." However, after I set the font-family of my website's elements to this, the font remained as the default Arial. I also tried other -apple-system font-families without "Circular" at the start, and it still did not work. I searched tutorials online and did not see any mentioning of downloading any dependency into the project. I am wondering what I missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some elements like `buttons` have a different browser specific `font-family` on default. You need to specifically `inherit` the `font-family` for those.

See below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&display=swap');

html {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

button.example {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>
On <u>paragraphs</u> for example the <i>font-family</i>&nbsp&nbspis inherited on default unlike on <u>buttons</u>
</p>
<button>
  Not inherited
</button>
<button class="example">
   inherited
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is the import statement necessary? I set the font-family attribute of html to "Circular, -apple-system..." (the one I brought up in the question) and the font-family of desired elements to "inherit," and it still did not work. Could you take a look at this specific font-family?

Comment: You are using a `font-stack` preceded by a `font`, that's not a `system-font`, in your case `Circular`. Your browser will loop through that `font-stack` list and will use the first `font` it recognizes, the others get either skipped (if before that certain font) or ignored (when behind that certain font), but in order to recognize a `font` it needs resources, on my Windows computer it will display `Helvetica Neue`, since it's the first `font` in that my system provides resources for. So yes for a none-system-font you need to provide resources through either an `@import` or a `download`.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer does not have Circular font installed. On Airbnb it is downloaded from provided in CSS url. If you want to use some nonstandard font you need to provide urls for them. You can check, e.g. [fonts.google.com](https://fonts.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bangers&display=swap');

html {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

button.example {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p>
On <u>paragraphs</u> for example the <i>font-family</i>&nbsp&nbspis inherited on default unlike on <u>buttons</u>
</p>
<button>
  Not inherited
</button>
<button class="example">
   inherited
</button>
```

[image: My statement]

[image: Deactivated]

[image: Transaction receipt]

[image: Tax invoice]

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**